# CSS buttons won't display inline and overflow div

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming and have been stuck for days trying to get my buttons to align horizontally in the center of their div. I have tried display: inline and display: inline-block and all the different solutions i have found on this forum and none have worked for me. Here is the css for the buttons:

```
  div.contact {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      background: #d6d6c2 url(https://clcadvisors.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/img_0914-0.jpg) no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
}

ul.soc {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

li.socbutton a {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px black;
  width: 250px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contact">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <div>
      <ul class="soc">
      <li class="socbutton">
        <a href="    https://www.linkedin.com/in/jason-conley-744b27111/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-linkedin-square fa-fw"></i>LINKEDIN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="socbutton">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/JHConley/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>TWITTER</a>
      </li>
      <li class="socbutton">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jason.conley.9231712/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></i>FACEBOOK</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the link to the codepen that I am building it in http://codepen.io/SHENKU360/pen/VedRbP

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome...but one thing. Stack Overflow is not a *forum*. They get picky about that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul.soc {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.soc li {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

This will align all the stuff inside your "unsorted list"-element to center. This element will also need a 100% width.
All list-elements inside should be `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inline the `li`s, not the `a`s:

```
li.socbutton {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And make the `ul` center them:

```
ul.soc {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your  css

```
li{
overflow: hidden;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:0px; }
```

this link is also helpfull https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/